# Most of the time I get '^?' instead of backspace action

Tags: command-line, keyboard, gnome-terminal

I am finding a lot of the time that if I press <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> I just get this in the GUI Terminal app:

```
^?
```

I also find that if I press <kbd>INSERT</kbd> that I get:

```
^[[2~
```

And this is becoming rather annoying as instead of it removing text, it just add more. Is there any way of fixing this? And anyway, why is it happening? Please comment if you need me to provide any more information.

**Information Update:**

When I launch Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and I press <kbd>INSERT</kbd>, I will get the output that I said above (most of the time), and no matter what I type, if I press <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> I will most likely just get its symbol, and not actually have anything deleted. Just to clarify, this will happen even if I have not executed any previous command in Terminal, I just have to type something and then press <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>.

The output of the command `stty -a` is:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 39; columns 72; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?;
eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon
-ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0
vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop
-echoprt echoctl echoke
```

I was requested to add the contents of this file `~/.inputrc` to my question, but this file does not exist, however, the other file with the same name, but different location does exist. So the contents of this file `/etc/inputrc` is:

```
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: Which terminal app?

Comment: @A.B.: The default Gnome one (although I'm in Unity). The default one that you get if you do "CTRL + ALT + T".

Comment: @A.B.: Although I also once in the past under special circumstances got it in one of the Linux Consoles. Them being that the machine was shutting down. But this was not the case when I was doing it in the other Terminal.

Comment: To show the Ctrl-Shift-T terminal: `sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: @A.B. The output of that (although without the `sudo`) was: `x-terminal-emulator            auto     /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`.

Comment: [edit] your question (don't keep tacking on comments) and tell the world _what program you are running on the emulated terminal_ and _what you are doing at the time_.  For all that poor answerers know, you're running `/bin/cat` after `stty raw`.

Comment: @JdeBP: Ok, well I think that I have updated my question to clarify that, but if you think that I need to add any more information please just let me know.

Comment: What is the content of `~/.inputrc` ? of `/etc/inputrc` ? Use a pastebin, please.

Comment: @solsTiCe why a pastebin? Please _don't_ use  a pastebin but add the contents of those files directly into your question. That is almost certainly where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @solsTiCe Ok, I have updated my question to include that information.

Comment: Although I did not put it in a pastebin, as @terdon said that I should not.

Comment: What does `echo "$TERM"` output?

Comment: @geirha: The output of that is `xterm`.

Comment: Good, and what shell is it?  `echo "$SHELL"; ps -p "$$"`

Comment: @geirha: And the output of that command is `/bin/bash
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
24225 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by editing the terminal profile.

1. Right-click in the terminal window and choose *Profiles >> Profile Preferences*
2. Or from the menu: *Edit >> Profile Preferences*
3. Navigate to the the compatibility tab and find '*Backspace key generates*'
4. Select '*ASCII DEL*'

If this did not help, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027040/vi-backspace-printing-in-insert-mode) and [this](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html).

Comment: It is already set to `ASCII DEL`.

Comment: Maybe its a keyboard problem. Are you using a USB or PS/2 keyboard.

Comment: Nope, I am using the built in keyboard in my Notebook.

Comment: Can you post the output of `stty -a` in your question

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question to include that information.